# How to make a non-overriding method stub in Python multi-inheritance?

Tags: python, virtual, multiple-inheritance

Imagine that you have 2 mixin classes, that each define abstract methods and implementations. Together they implement every method, but depending on the inheritance order, the empty stubs will overwrite the implementation from the other class. There's at least two ways to overcome this in most situations but I don't really like either.

1. One could remove the abstract methods and just rely on duck typing, but then there is no clear interface definition and type hinting.
2. One could try to break down the classes into smaller ones to get a straight line of dependency and force a specific inheritance order, but that's not always practical.

Is there a way to, for example, mark a method *virtual*, which prevents it from actually being added to the class, or at least prevents it from overriding an existing method of the same name?

Is there another solution I didn't think of?

Simple example:

```
class MixinA:
    def high_level(self):
        self.mid_level()

    def low_level(self):
        ...

    def mid_level(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class MixinB:
    def mid_level(self):
        self.low_level()

    def low_level(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class ChildA(MixinA, MixinB):
    pass


class ChildB(MixinB, MixinA):
    pass


for cls in (ChildA, ChildB):
    try:
        cls().high_level()
        print("success")
    except NotImplementedError:
        print("error")
```

Comment: I think `super` based calls can proceed to call siblings in MRO.  You could then `pass` instead of raising errors.  Second it doesnt make any sense to put NotImplementeds on a Mixin.  That’s **not** what the concept is about and if you’re privileging linting and type hinting over basic Python mechanisms you’re losing the plot, IMHO.  Put an ABC then concrete classes inheriting frm *some* mixins as needed, implementing *real* methods.

Comment: The super call has the same resolution order as the overriding, would basically have to call super in the stub method. I generally prefer to have type checking on and resolve all type issues, saves me a lot of time in testing. It's also nicer to document the interface in code instead of docstrings when you can. It would be nice to solve this with protocols or some virtual method magic.

Comment: Point is, a mixin is not supposed to be a concrete class.  So let the ABC do its job by checking that your, absent in your code, concrete classes have the right combination of methods to be instantiated.  You shouldn't try to instantiate Mixins.  Come to think of it why don't you use abc's [abstract method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod) mechanism in your sample actual code, rather than just talk about abstract methods?

Comment: There is no **virtual** method keyword in Python.  Not sure how protocols fit with your Q which seems a bit of an X-Y problem.  Protocols are more about declaration and type-checking than they are about implementation (those pesky NotImplementedError s lurking in your Mixins which do **not** belong there).  Check the abc system, it will happily reject your class instantiations if you haven't slotted in the right method implementations, either directly in concrete classes or via Mixin-based inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that satisfies my requirements, that is:

- it describes an interface which the inheriting class needs to implement
- does not override existing functions with abstract functions
- is typing compatible

Basically, I just defined the abstract functions in a separate protocol and marked the self var as that protocol.

```py
from typing import Protocol


class InterfaceForA(Protocol):
    def mid_level(self): ...


class MixinA:
    def high_level(self: InterfaceForA):
        self.mid_level()

    def low_level(self):
        print("success")


class InterfaceForB(Protocol):
    def low_level(self): ...


class MixinB:
    def mid_level(self: InterfaceForB):
        self.low_level()


class ChildA(MixinA, MixinB):
    pass


class ChildB(MixinB, MixinA):
    pass


for cls in ChildA, ChildB:
    try:
        cls().high_level()
    except:
        print("error")
```

With this code, I get success printed twice. In addition, the type hints let me know if the method implementations in the mixin are incompatible with the requirements defined in the protocols.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is what an [ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod)-based implementation might look like.

You just have to mix and match the Mixins to achieve what you want.  The Mixins only implement what they are actually providing.

**mypy** will flag errors during *type-checking*
**abc** will also throw errors about missing methods *at runtime*

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class AbstractLevel(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def high_level(self):
        ...

    @abstractmethod
    def low_level(self):
        ...

    @abstractmethod
    def mid_level(self):
        ...

class MixinHighMid:

    def high_level(self):
        self.mid_level()

class MixinMid:

    def mid_level(self):
        print(f"    MixinMid.mid_level")

class ConcreteLow(MixinHighMid, MixinMid, AbstractLevel):
    def low_level(self):
        print(f"    {self}.low_level")

class BadConcreteLow(MixinHighMid,AbstractLevel):

    def low_level(self):
        print(f"{self}.low_level")


for cls in (ConcreteLow, BadConcreteLow):

    good = ConcreteLow()   #happy mypy
    try:
        bad = BadConcreteLow() #sad mypy
    except (TypeError,) as e:
        pass
    
    try:
        print(cls.__name__)
        inst = cls()  #sad mypy because knows BadConcreteLow will blow up
        print(f"  calling high_level")
        inst.high_level()
    except (TypeError,) as e:
        print(f"error on {cls.__name__}: {e}")
```

##### runtime output:

```
ConcreteLow
  calling high_level
    MixinMid.mid_level
BadConcreteLow
error on BadConcreteLow: Can't instantiate abstract class BadConcreteLow with abstract method mid_level
```

#### and mypy output:

```
test_418_mixindecl.py:41: error: Cannot instantiate abstract class "BadConcreteLow" with abstract attribute "mid_level"
test_418_mixindecl.py:49: error: Cannot instantiate abstract class "AbstractLevel" with abstract attributes "high_level", "low_level" and "mid_level"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

To amuse myself, I also added the following Mixin to mangle method signatures:

```
class BadMixinMid:

    def mid_level(self, v : int):
        print(f"    MixinMid.mid_level")

class BadConcreteMid(MixinHighMid,BadMixinMid,AbstractLevel):

    def low_level(self):
        print(f"{self}.low_level")
```

**mypy** caught that on type-checking while the runtime only blew up on the method call itself.

```
test_418_mixindecl.py:41: error: Definition of "mid_level" in base class "BadMixinMid" is incompatible with definition in base class "AbstractLevel"
```

Comment: The point of my example was that the flow from High->Mid->Low is from mixin classes A->B->A. There is no implementation in the child because all implementation comes from the mixins. In your example there is no call to low, so the flow is only High->Mid. If you added a call from mid to low, you would have a call to an undeclared function in the mixin, which is fine if you don't care about documenting the dependency of the 'mixin'. Also requires an abstract class definition. I think the main problem is just having dependencies in the mixin.